# Definition of a vector field on a differentiable manifold.

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, manifolds, vectors

Wikipedia defines the vector field at a point on a manifold to lie in its tangent space. But is this general enough? Consider a surface traction vector on some manifold, for example. It will have a component in the normal direction. Is this not considered a vector field then since it doesn't lie in the tangent space?

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, it is not a vector field on the surface, for the reason you wrote. Such a thing is called *a vector field along the inclusion of the surface in the ambient manifold*. What it basically means is that at any point on the surface there is a vector tangent to the ambient space (and not necessarily to the surface).

Answer (score 1):

More generally this could be described in terms of *vector bundles*,

> A vector bundle ... makes precise the idea of a family of vector
>   spaces parameterized by another space X ...: to every point x of the
>   space X we associate (or "attach") a vector space V(x) ..., which is
>   then called a vector bundle over X.

... and *sections*,

> Essentially, a section assigns to every point ... a vector from the
>   attached vector space, in a continuous manner.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_bundle